# laravel eloquent ORM update and delete

Tags: laravel, post, eloquent, updates

How to combine POST and UPDATE commands in one action in laravel 8 with ajax?

I have one column "status" in another table that I need to update when I save the data.

In this case basically I have two different tables... thank you for your answer!

##### Update from the comments:

I have two different database tables, let's say the "Quotation" and "Detail Quotation" tables, where in the "Detail Quotation" table there is a Status column that contains TRUE or FALSE...

Well, I want when I add data to the Quotation table, I also run the command to change the contents of the status column in the "Detail Quotation" table.

Comment: Please post some code as well to understand the problem better

Comment: I have two different database tables, let's say the "Quotation" and "Detail Quotation" tables, where in the "Detail Quotation" table there is a Status column that contains TRUE OR FALSE... well, I want when I add data to the Quotation table, I also run the command to change the contents of the status column in the "Detail Quotation" table

Answer (score 0):

you must use observer for this case
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 0):

When you save the POST data in table. Laravel return ID then, with that ID you can call the update function for another table to update the status.